# Can kernel be written in other than assembly language?

Tags: java, kernel

I never did kernel programming. I am a good programmer in the Java language and frequently use it. Now i feel to do something interesting with kernels. A kernel resides between hardware and OS. It communicates with hardware using system calls. Every programming language require a compiler to compile the code written in high level language and then it generate low level code, which is generally assembly language code. Here comes my doubt, *if we have kernel written in C, then should we have a C compiler installed on the machine?* At the end, when kernel interacts with hardware it uses assembly language, can i create kernel in Java language? If yes, then what are the requirements for the same? Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why are you marking stuff as code that's not code?

Comment: I think you are confusing assembly language with machine instructions.

Comment: This is off topic here. Theoretical Computer Science, perhaps? Probably OT there, too

Comment: @GGG: Yeah. Niklas posted the answer. I was talking about machine instruction but i was confused!

Comment: I recommend a book like http://www.amazon.com/Operating-Systems-Implementation-Prentice-Hall-Software/dp/0136374069/ref=sr_1_36?ie=UTF8&qid=1358355695&sr=8-36&keywords=operating+systems+design+implementation.  It contains the entire source for the minix kernel, and you'll see what they had to implement in assembly (e.g. saving registers on CPU interrupt) because not even C offered a way to do it.  There are more recent versions of the book, but I estimate that OS basics haven't changed that much (someone correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: Of course, you can dig to find out how JNode is implemented if you find time (I don't know how).  Java programs run on a JVM, which does what it does (e.g. garbage collection) because someone wrote a JVM.  The JVM, whatever source language it is written in, must be compiled to machine code at some point before you can run any of your Java programs.  I expect that normal JVM's use OS system calls, like any other standard programs, to do many basic things.

Comment: Some reasons why C has been used to write probably most Unix-like OSes is that its runtime and standard library are relatively easy to implement--they do not provide as many features as Java--and C compilers have output to many different machine architectures for a very long time.  Also, it provides necessary features like pointers and treating data as arbitrary data--an OS kernel really needs this kind of thing.  Java is not designed for the same things.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> A kernel resides between hardware and OS

Usually, the kernel is considered to be *part* of the operating system.

> It communicates with hardware using system calls

System calls are the interface that is provided by the OS to user applications. The operating system communicates with the hardware through other mechanisms (for example interrupts or memory-mapped registers).

> Every programming language require a compiler to compile the code written in high level language and then it generate low level code, which is generally assembly language code.

The compiler output is typically either native machine code or a language-specific bytecode (like in the case of Java). Sometimes, compilers also target another programming language such as C or Javascript (transpilation).

> Here comes my doubt, if we have kernel written in C, then should we have a C compiler installed on the machine?

That's not necessary. The C compiler produces output that can execute directly on the hardware  without interpretation.

> At the end, when kernel interacts with hardware it uses assembly language

The CPU doesn't understand assembly. It understands machine code.

> can i create kernel in Java language?

It [has been done](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JNode).

> If yes, then what are the requirements for the same?

If you want to write a kernel in Java, then you either have to

- compile your entire Java codebase to machine code
- get yourself a [CPU that can execute Java bytecode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_processor)
- find or build a Java VM and runtime that can run on bare metal and run your Java code in it (if you do it cleverly, you can write much of the runtime and maybe also parts of the VM in Java itself).

Now to the unspoken, almost rhethorical question:

> Is this a good idea?

Probably not. Why? First of all, because it would take ages to set up. Second, because you couldn't just code the way you develop an average business application. You'd have to think about performance of very time-critical code (e.g. context switching, which often requires hand-tuned assembly to be fast enough), manual memory management (as in: your MRU might expect you to give it the physical address where the page table lies), system-/hardware-specific mechanisms (how to access a XYZ controller on this particular architecture?), ...

So you would lose many of the advantages that Java has over a low-level language like C in the first place.

Comment: No, you just really need the runtime to execute on the bare metal, you don't necessarily need the majority of the kernel logic to be in machine code. Obviously, it's a layer of indirection compared to running flat out on the CPU it self, but when the runtime includes a JIT, that effectively goes away in time.

Comment: @Will: That's actually what I had in mind too. Lemme edit to reflect this.

Comment: @NiklasB. `get yourself a CPU that can execute Java bytecode` What does it mean? Do you mean that machine must have JRE installed? Right now i have Intel Core 2 Duo t5670 @ 1.80GHz

Comment: @Ravi: No, I mean [*hardware* that can execute Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_processor). Your JRE just uses the operating system's APIs (which obviously isn't available if you code your own OS).

Comment: @NiklasB. So you mean that my Intel processor wont work. Can you specify any other hardware which supports it? Can i use any `virtual machine` software to make such environment just for educational purpose?

Comment: @NiklasB.: calm down, it's OPs privilege to accept any answer he finds to be the best - and your privilege is to downvote bad answers - but the accepted one is shorter, but not incorrect or bad. However I personally find your answer much better, +1 from me :-).

Comment: @NiklasB.: It was an accident. My connection was down while i was playing some game over internet. I apologize. I just vote that up.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz: I didn't do that knowingly. My connection was down. I apologize for that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes a kernel can be written in Java, see the [JNode](http://www.jnode.org/). It would have the advantage of having no problems with: dangling pointers, mix up of pointers and array addresses, unitialised data, and many more features of C.

Comment: And what about the hardware requirements?

Comment: @Ravi: JNode takes the approach of compiling the operating system code to machine code, so it doesn't have any special hardware requirements.